# Is anyone able to understand how to add these minifloat (1 bit sign, 3 bit exponent, 4 bit fraction) bit numbers?

Tags: floating-point, binary, numbers

I have a task where we add two binary numbers, but I do not understand the solution.

Previously, it is so we have given binary numbers, in minifloat format. In our case, the minifloat is defined like this:

- the first bit is the sign.
- Then we have 3 bits for the exponent ( with excess constant 3)
- and 4 bits for the fraction (mantissa).
- In addition, we work with denormalized representation, i.e. that all exponent bits are =0 and also with normalized representation, i.e. all other cases when the exponent bits are not all 0.

Now we have the two minifloat numbers:

- 01010011
- 01100100

We are to add these and then represent them again as minifloats. To be able to add them, the two numbers are converted into fixed point numbers.
According to the documentation, the fixed point numbers represent the minifloats in this format:

- 5 digits before the decimal point (with fraction=4 and exponent=4 (normalized) )
- 6 decimal places (With the length of fraction=4 and exponent=-2)
  This is how the addition is, according to the sample solution:

1. conversion of minifloats to fixed point number:

   0 101 0011 = 1.0011 * 2^2 = 00100.110000

   0 110 0100 = 1.0100 * 2^3= 01010.000000
2. binary adding:

   00100.110000 + 01010.000000= 01110.110000
3. move decimal point:

   1.1101100000 * 2^3 (What I don't get here, why do I shift the
   decimal point by 2^3 and
   why did I add a 0 to it, is that maybe a typo? Have here one zero
   more than with
   01110.110000)
4. truncate the decimal places and round if necessary:

   1.1101(100000)*  2^3
   -->round up, because first truncated bit 1 (But how do I know where
   I always truncate, here it was after the 5 bit , is that always the
   case?)
   -->1.1110*2^3
5. result as minifloat:

   **0 110 1110** (Now you have here the result somehow formed from the
   4, but do not understand how, how do you get from 1.1110*2^3 to
   01101110)

So somehow I understand the 5 steps very very little, is anyone able to analyze what one did here?

Comment: "Is anyone able to understand how to add these minifloat (1 bit sign, 3 bit exponent, 4 bit fraction) bit numbers?" --> Yes.  "is anyone able to analyze what one did here?" --> Yes.  Better to ask a direct question about what specifically is needed than such a yes/no  question with its veiled - please explain all to me implication.  That is too broad.

Comment: Hi thank you, I dont understand why we make in Step 3 *2^3 and how we get the 110 in Step 5.